# Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned disables autocomplete feature

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

With Windows PowerShell default color setting, the error text is unreadable.

So i created a config file in the $profile location and set the executionPolicy to RemoteSigned.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

However doing this disables the default features of PowerShell like autocomplete etc.

I also tried executionPolicy to unrestricted. Same problem.

Default policy for all is Undefined as i checked with Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

Comment: Autocomplete as in Tab?

Comment: @NekoMusume yes Tab to autocomplete

Comment: Try `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function Complete`